# Error with starting Openvswitch on wsl2

Tags: kernel-modules, windows-subsystem-for-linux

How do I fix that following errors

```
root@DESKTOP-OK32G:/mnt/c/Windows/system32# service openvswitch-switch start
modprobe: FATAL: Module openvswitch not found in directory /lib/modules/5.10.102.1-microsoft-standard-WSL2
 * Inserting openvswitch module
rmmod: ERROR: ../libkmod/libkmod-module.c:1941 kmod_module_get_holders() could not open '/sys/module/bridge/holders': No such file or directory
rmmod: ERROR: Module unloading is not supported
* removing bridge module
 * ovsdb-server is already running
modprobe: FATAL: Module openvswitch not found in directory /lib/modules/5.10.102.1-microsoft-standard-WSL2
* Inserting openvswitch module
rmmod: ERROR: ../libkmod/libkmod-module.c:1941 kmod_module_get_holders() could not open '/sys/module/bridge/holders': No such file or directory
rmmod: ERROR: Module unloading is not supported
* removing bridge module
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Mininet documentation states: "VM installation is the easiest and most foolproof way of installing Mininet, so it’s what we recommend to start with".
Therefore, I suggest you setup the VM as suggested by the docs: http://mininet.org/download/

Secondly: if you really want to use openvswitch inside WSL, you will probably have to recompile the kernel with the required modules. This process is not beginner friendly, and would take a lot of time and research.

TLDR: if you want to quickly have mininet up and running, please use the VM. Otherwise, you will have lots of trouble.

Answer (score 0):

Ran across this same error while trying to run mininet ('sudo mn').

Had this problem initially on my WSL 2 running Ubuntu 18, did some digging on troubleshooting openvswitch and after trying many fixes opted for making a new, clean ubuntu vm.

Currently on my WSL 2 running Ubuntu 20.04.5 LTS, in which the only commands I've run since have been:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade
sudo apt install mininet
```

After set up I tried running the openvswitch service since it's a requirement for mininet to work properly and got the follolwing output:

```
rj@Ubuntu:~$ sudo service openvswitch-switch start
modprobe: FATAL: Module openvswitch not found in directory /lib/modules/5.10.102.1-microsoft-standard-WSL2
 * Inserting openvswitch module
rmmod: ERROR: ../libkmod/libkmod-module.c:1941 kmod_module_get_holders() could not open '/sys/module/bridge/holders': No such file or directory
rmmod: ERROR: Module unloading is not supported
 * removing bridge module
2022-11-13T00:03:48Z|00001|dns_resolve|WARN|Failed to read etc/hosts: syntax error
 * Starting ovsdb-server
2022-11-13T00:03:48Z|00001|dns_resolve|WARN|Failed to read etc/hosts: syntax error
 * Configuring Open vSwitch system IDs
modprobe: FATAL: Module openvswitch not found in directory /lib/modules/5.10.102.1-microsoft-standard-WSL2
 * Inserting openvswitch module
rmmod: ERROR: ../libkmod/libkmod-module.c:1941 kmod_module_get_holders() could not open '/sys/module/bridge/holders': No such file or directory
rmmod: ERROR: Module unloading is not supported
 * removing bridge module
```

Tried troubleshooting the 'dns_resolve' error with: https://github.com/actions/runner-images/issues/3353#issuecomment-838881751
with no success.

Due to the faulty openvswitch start, mininet hangs on start while opening switches:

```
rj@Ubuntu:~$ sudo mn
*** No default OpenFlow controller found for default switch!
*** Falling back to OVS Bridge
*** Creating network
*** Adding controller
*** Adding hosts:
h1 h2
*** Adding switches:
s1
*** Adding links:
(h1, s1) (h2, s1)
*** Configuring hosts
h1 h2
*** Starting controller

*** Starting 1 switches
s1 ...
```

Output for ovs-vswitchd --version:

```
rj@Ubuntu:~$ ovs-vswitchd --version
2022-11-13T00:22:47Z|00001|dns_resolve|WARN|Failed to read etc/hosts: syntax error
ovs-vswitchd (Open vSwitch) 2.13.8
```

Answer (score 0):

[This link](https://zenn.dev/takai404/articles/9c96d5d1bcc9d0) helps.

tldr;

For Windows 11, WSL2, in /etc/wsl.conf file,

```
[boot]
systemd=true
```

Build the kernel with OpenvSwitch from Networking Options and at the end, open wsl with new kernel and run `sudo make modules_install` from the same (kernel build) directory. Then reinstall openvswitch-switch with apt.